# Is it possible to distinguish that request is from UIWebView or from iPhone's safari?

Tags: ios, http, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I want to be able to distinguish http requests. Could I achieve this using IP, user agent or other means?

Answer (score 0):

Is the `UIWebView` hosted in an app you're writing? If so, you should be able to manually manage the connection to the server with an `NSURLConnection` and add or change headers that are sent with the HTTP request to pass whatever information you need to the server.

Comment: No, it isn't. I wonder is there any unique (and immutable) thing in requests sent by UIWebView control so I could identify these kinds of requests?

Comment: Have you tried watching the requests your server gets to see if there's a difference between `UIWebView`'s and Mobile Safari's requests?